# How to enable WoW/WoWLAN

Tags: wifi, wlan, wake-on-lan

What do you enable/disable Wireless Wake On LAN/Wake on Wifi/Wake on Wireless LAN so that a magic packet can wake the server/PC up?

Answer (score 2):

## Please note that not all WiFi cards or Linux drivers support the WoWLAN feature.

---

First of all, let's find the Wireless Interface with `iw list`, `iw dev` and note it down (I'll assume it's the default `phy0` from this point on)

### Enabling WoWLAN

`sudo iw phy0 wowlan enable magic-packet` (you can also specify on disconnect (you write only disconnect) to enable that function)

### Disable WoWLAN

`sudo iw phy0 wowlan disable`

### Determine status of WoWLAN

`iw phy0 wowlan show`

### More info

`man iw`
`iw --help`

Comment: Having just for the first time tried this, everything goes without error and positive 'WoWLAN is enabled' output. But no response on `wakeonlan <MAC>`. Perhaps answer could confirm tooling to wake-up per wifi is the same as ethernet.

Comment: Maybe it's a networking issue?

Comment: @mpe I had the same issue and found that I had to use `wakeonlan -i=<ip> <MAC>`, without setting the ip address `wakeonlan` would use the wrong one.